# Python .csv labeling done properly via jupyter

Tags: python, pandas, networkx

I'm not sure if my graphs are done properly, what will happen if I'd want to go with upside down. I'd like also to print and generate file as `.pdf`. But I'm not quite sure how to accomplish that task, please give me some advice if you have any. I'd appreciate that, all best.

Changing variables countlessly

```
import numpy as np
np.__version__
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from operator import itemgetter

sns.set(style="darkgrid")

# t 1

m1 = np.array([[1,2,2],[-4,3,8],[-1,0,1]])
m2 = np.array([[1,4],[-2,2],[3,-6]])

print(m1.dot(m2));


# t 2

G = nx.Graph()

G.add_edges_from([
    ('A','D'),('A','B'),('B','D'),('B','C'),('B','E'),('C','D'),('C','E'),('D','E')
])
nx.draw(G, with_labels=True)

array = nx.betweenness_centrality(G)
array['B']

# t 3

df = pd.read_csv('xxx.csv')
df.set_index('OBJECTID', inplace=True)

df.head(1)

# t 4

sorted = df.groupby('NAME')['PT_ENROLL'].sum().sort_values(ascending=False)
sorted.head(7)

# t 5

df.groupby('NAICS_DESC')['NAME'].count().sort_values(ascending=False)

# t 6
df1 = df['TOT_ENROLL']
df2 = df['POPULATION']

plt.scatter(df1,df2)
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what your question is.  What output do you want, and what do you have?  Please look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

```
# T3
df = pd.read_csv('Hospitals.csv')
df.set_index('OBJECTID', inplace=True)

df.head(5)

# T4
sorted = df.groupby('CITY')['NAME'].count().sort_values(ascending=False)
sorted.head(6)

# T5
sorted = df.groupby('NAME')['Y'].max().sort_values(ascending=False)
sorted.head(5)

# T6
df.groupby('OWNER')['BEDS'].sum().sort_values(ascending=False).plot(kind='bar')
```